# Fiction book identification

Tags: story-identification, magic

This story I read last year was about a town that was filled with sorrows and someone who ate those sorrows. They sacrificed a child who ate the moonlight and became magical. It all falls into a part where all main characters come together and a volcano erupts. I know this is specific but I can't remember names (Besides Luna) and I loved the story. can someone try to identify this?

Comment: The person ate the sorrows not the people

Comment: Book or short story? Where did you read it, and in what language? Where does the name Luna fit in?

Comment: Also, was it new when you read it? Or is it an older work? Where did you get it from?

Comment: YES! It was the girl who drank the moon. I found it in my little sister's room and that was EXACTLY the one I was thinking about! thank yall so much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [*The Girl Who Drank the Moon*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1616205679)

It has the girl who ate moonlight (as you could guess from the title):

> The moon had grown full without her noticing. And powerfully magic.
>   One sip would have done it, and the baby had had—well. More than one
>   sip.

The person who ate sorrows:

> Xan turned to the young man. “You wanted to find the Witch? This is
>   your witch, my friend. You call her Sister Ignatia?” She gave the
>   stranger a skeptical look. “How fancy. I knew her by a different name,
>   though I called her the monster when I was a child. She has been
>   living off the Protectorate’s sorrow for—how long has it been? Five
>   hundred years. My goodness. That’s something for the history books,
>   isn’t it? You must be very proud of yourself.”
>
> The stranger surveyed the scene, a small smile pressed into her mouth.
>   Sorrow Eater, Luna thought. A hateful term for a hateful person.

And the volcanic eruption:

> The volcano sent forth a column of fire and smoke, swallowed power
>   un-swallowed at last.